# How to insert a changing string from a function into a label in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've asked a similar question before with a simple loop, however, I am struggling with a more complex script. Area of the function which I am trying to insert into a label in the GUI:

```
def all():
    ##INPUTS FROM THE USER 
    #User Inputs
    vin_list_input1 = vin.get()
    vin_list_input = [item for item in vin_list_input1.split()]
    adobe_input = path.get()
    #Conversion
    listvin = vin_list_input
    listnum = []

    ##MAIN FUNCTION THAT FINDS NEEDED PAGES
    #Pdf Object
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(adobe_input)
    # Get number of pages
    NumPages = object.getNumPages()
    def find_pg():
        for vin in listvin:
            # Extract text and do the search
            for i in range(0, NumPages):
                PageObj = object.getPage(i)
                Text = PageObj.extractText()
                if re.search(vin,Text):
                    listnum.append(i)
                    listnum.append(i+1)
            progress = (len(listnum)/2)/len(listvin)*100 #<----THIS PART INTO LABEL
            print(round(progress,2),end="\r")
    find_pg()
```

The part that I want to be a label is progress. It shows the progress of the script. I've tried several things but I keep on getting an error or the number does not update. Please help guys, I've been trying to figure this out for ages, I am a bit of a noob with Tkinter.

Btw the whole script is shown below:

```
def all():
    ##INPUTS FROM THE USER 
    #User Inputs
    vin_list_input1 = vin.get()
    vin_list_input = [item for item in vin_list_input1.split()]
    adobe_input = path.get()
    #Conversion
    listvin = vin_list_input
    listnum = []

    ##MAIN FUNCTION THAT FINDS NEEDED PAGES
    #Pdf Object
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(adobe_input)
    # Get number of pages
    NumPages = object.getNumPages()
    def find_pg():
        for vin in listvin:
            # Extract text and do the search
            for i in range(0, NumPages):
                PageObj = object.getPage(i)
                Text = PageObj.extractText()
                if re.search(vin,Text):
                    listnum.append(i)
                    listnum.append(i+1)
            progress = (len(listnum)/2)/len(listvin)*100
            print(round(progress,2),end="\r")
    find_pg()

    ##CONCATING ALL OF THE FILES
    adobe_input = adobe_input[:-4]

    pdf_file_path = adobe_input + '.pdf'
    file_base_name = pdf_file_path.replace('.pdf', '')

    pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file_path)

    pages = listnum 
    pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()

    for page_num in pages:
        pdfWriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))

    with open('{0}_subset.pdf'.format(file_base_name), 'wb') as f:
        pdfWriter.write(f)
        f.close()

    ##SAVING THE NEW FILE AND SENDING IT TO THE PRINTER
    os.startfile(adobe_input + "_subset" + ".pdf" , 'print')

##INTERFACE TKINTER
window = Tk()
window.title("Ctrl + F Automator ™")
window.geometry("592x150")

l_emp1 = Label(window, text = "",justify = LEFT).grid(sticky = W, row = 0, column =0)
l_emp2 = Label(window, text = "",justify = LEFT).grid(sticky = W, row = 3, column =0)

l_vin_list = Label(window, text = "Enter VIN's: ", justify = LEFT).grid(sticky = W, row = 1, column =1)
l_path = Label(window, text = "Enter PDF path: ",justify = LEFT).grid(sticky = W, row = 2, column =1)

vin = StringVar()
path = StringVar()
e1 = tk.Entry(window, text = vin, width = 80)
e2 = tk.Entry(window, text = path, width = 80)
e1.grid(row=1, column=2)
e2.grid(row=2, column=2)

b_enter = Button(window, text ="Conirm & Launch Script", command = all, width = 80, height = 1).place(x=10, y=80)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `config(text=progress)` where you want to change the text.

Comment: or You can use a `StringVar()` and its `set()` method, tho You have to provide the Label with textvariable for example: `Label(parent, textvariable=text_var)` where `text_var` is defined as: `text_var = StringVar()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change a label's text with `config(text=progress)`:

```
from tkinter import *

def clicked():
    l.config(text='changed!')
    
    
root = Tk()

l = Label(text='Click button to change text')
b = Button(text='click', command=clicked)

l.pack()
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: 2 things: using plain `mainloop()` is not the best practice and for code formatting use ``` (as You can see in my edit)

Comment: @Matiiss thanks, your solution seems to partially work. the label only updates to 100% after the function is finished. It seems to skip the other number like 50%. Do you have any idea why that is happening?

Comment: either You are not updating the `StringVar()` or Your loop interferes with `mainloop()` thus causing it to update only when the loop ends, so I suggest using [`.after()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/) for such loops, alternatively You could put the `StringVar()` inside such a loop and update it

Comment: I believe that my loop interferes with the mainloop(). But if I want to use .after() wouldn't I have to make progress (the string) into a separate function, or am I mislead? @Matiiss

Comment: @MarkasPovilaika I can't think of an easy way to do that right now, but does using `.config(text=string)` do the same in that some strings are not updated? anyhow there is also a possibility to run the loop using threading (not suggested) but that should definitely work, for that YOu will have to look up some tutorials, too long to explain here and a tutorial will probably do better

Comment: @Matiiss `mainloop()` and `w.mainloop()` are literally the same thing. In this case especially. The only difference is the instance of `Tk` it works on.

Comment: @CoolCloud well I heard that it is bad practice so even if the same thing why use also it won't make matters worse so why not just add?

Comment: @Matiiss Please make sure to ask the user for permission before editing their code with new one. You are free to correct grammars and so on, but not code.

Comment: @CoolCloud well in my case the user has to accept the edit but great advice for later, also the only part of me editing their code was adding `root.` but otherwise I just added more code that wasn't theirs so not really editing their code or shouldn't I do that either?

Comment: @Matiiss Actually no, you added your code, maybe someone looking it would misunderstand for it being the users. You can always just add your own answer if your code is different from the existing answers.

Comment: This is the correct answer the only thing that was missing was root.update_idletasks()  inside the function. After adding that everything works perfectly. Thanks @CoolCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to change label text (using StringVar):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label,Button, StringVar


def clicked():
    text_var.set('changed')
    
    
root = Tk()

text_var = StringVar()
text_var.set('Click button to change text')
lbl = Label(textvariable=text_var)
btn = Button(text='click', command=clicked)

lbl.pack()
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

`StringVar`s are especially great (IMO) if creating widgets in a loop.

Comment: IMO, `StringVar` is useless, unless its a group widget or so. In loops, you should store the widgets inside a list or so. There is no point in using `StringVar`, when widgets by default has its own `insert` and `delete` methods. Not to mention, widgets like `Text` cannot take a `textvariable` at all. I would only ever use `StringVar` for using its `trace` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Btw the code that worked completely:

```
def all():
    ##INPUTS FROM THE USER 
    #User Inputs
    vin_list_input1 = vin.get()
    vin_list_input = [item for item in vin_list_input1.split()]
    adobe_input = path.get()
    #Conversion
    listvin = vin_list_input
    listnum = []

    ##MAIN FUNCTION THAT FINDS NEEDED PAGES
    #Pdf Object
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(adobe_input)
    # Get number of pages
    NumPages = object.getNumPages()
    def find_pg():
        for vin in listvin:
            # Extract text and do the search
            for i in range(0, NumPages):
                PageObj = object.getPage(i)
                Text = PageObj.extractText()
                if re.search(vin,Text):
                    listnum.append(i)
                    listnum.append(i+1)
            progress = (len(listnum)/2)/len(listvin)*100
            progress = round(progress,2)
            progress = str(progress) + '%'
            #print(round(progress,2),end = "\r")
            l_progress.config(text = progress)
            window.update_idletasks() 
    find_pg()

    ##CONCATING ALL OF THE FILES
    adobe_input = adobe_input[:-4]

    pdf_file_path = adobe_input + '.pdf'
    file_base_name = pdf_file_path.replace('.pdf', '')

    pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file_path)

    pages = listnum # page 1, 3, 5
    pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()

    for page_num in pages:
        pdfWriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))

    with open('{0}_subset.pdf'.format(file_base_name), 'wb') as f:
        pdfWriter.write(f)
        f.close()

    ##SAVING THE NEW FILE AND SENDING IT TO THE PRINTER
    os.startfile(adobe_input + "_subset" + ".pdf" , 'print')

##INTERFACE TKINTER
window = Tk()
window.title("Ctrl + F Automator ™")
window.geometry("592x155")
window.wm_iconbitmap('desktop/Gu/logo.ico')

l_emp1 = Label(window, text = "",justify = LEFT).grid(sticky = W, row = 0, column =0)
l_emp2 = Label(window, text = "",justify = LEFT).grid(sticky = W, row = 3, column =0)

l_vin_list = Label(window, text = "Enter VIN's: ", justify = LEFT).grid(sticky = W, row = 1, column =1)
l_path = Label(window, text = "Enter PDF path: ",justify = LEFT).grid(sticky = W, row = 2, column =1)

l_load = Label(window, text = "Search Complete:",justify = LEFT).place(x = 10,y =120)

l_progress = Label(text = '0.0' + '%')
l_progress.place(x=106,y=120)

vin = StringVar()
path = StringVar()
e1 = tk.Entry(window, text = vin, width = 80)
e2 = tk.Entry(window, text = path, width = 80)
e1.grid(row=1, column=2)
e2.grid(row=2, column=2)

b_enter = Button(window, text ="Conirm & Launch Script", command = all, width = 80, height = 1).place(x=10, y=80)

window.mainloop()
```